# I want to get id from database and use it in other class in Android app

Tags: android

In database I have written the following code to get `id`.

```
public int getID(){

      String[] columns = new String[]{ID};      
        Cursor c=ourDB.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if(c.getCount()==0)
            return 1;
        c.moveToLast();
        int id=c.getInt(0);
        return id+1;
    }
```

And in the class I did

```
int id = info.getID();
```

But the `id` is not incrementing after each entry and stays 1.

Comment: You need last id inserted or generating new id based last inserted id?

Comment: What value is it showing and what are you expecting? Why are you returning `id+1` at the end, btw?

Comment: "But it is not showing the right value of id." - So what is it showing, and what do you expect to see? This link may provide some insight, if, as I suspect its to do with how ids are automatically assigned using AUTOINCREMENT https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Where do you change the "id" value? You only access the id value.